# When to monitor battery capacity

Tags: batteries, 12v, discharge

While other [good answers](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/177032/how-bad-is-it-to-undervoltage-a-12-volt-lead-acid-battery?rq=1&newreg=ce51016c836a49adb7f9b3d173763e25) have stated why discharging a 12V lead acid battery is hurtful to it, I seem to be unable to find how you should monitor it.

Assuming I want to stop drawing current from the battery when it is at 50% charge, to avoid too much permanent damage. When the answers like [this one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/296750/228125) states the amount of cycles you can have with each DOD, it does not state how it should be measured. As voltage drops during discharge, the battery may (correctly) show a [lower voltage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/351352/designing-a-battery-capacity-monitoring-system-for-agm-lead-acid-battery) with a multimeter than without any load on it, where it will quickly rise to a larger voltage.

To avoid damage, should I stop drawing current when the battery is at 50% during a discharge, or when it is at 50% with no load?

Comment: 50% with no load. And don't let anyone tell you otherwise.

Comment: 50% **capacity** is the same regardless of whether there is a load or not. What you are really asking is whether you should use the **voltage** under load or with no load to estimate the capacity.